# Symfony Generator Forms, Doctrine, and M:N Relationships

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Symfony Generator Forms, Doctrine, and M:N Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309345/symfony-generator-forms-doctrine-and-mn-relationships)

I have a basic M:N setup with three tables: candidate, position, and candidate_position. Here's my best stab at a crow's-foot style ERD with just text

```
[candiate]-||------|<[candidate_position]>|------||-[position]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is this: When a `candidate` is being created or edited, the form will include a checkbox array of all available positions to assign to the candidate.

In the normal world of web app development, this is really, really easy.  But I'm trying to increase my competency with symfony's admin generator.  Here's what I've got so far

**apps/backend/modules/condidate/config/generator.yml**

```
generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           Candidate
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          candidate
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

    config:
      actions: ~
      fields:  
    first_name: { label: First Name }
    last_name:  { label: Last Name }
    created_at: { label: Created On }
    positions:  {}
      list:    
    sort:  [last_name, asc]
      filter:  ~
      form:    
    display:
      "User": [first_name, last_name]
      "Applying For": [positions]
    fields :
      hide:  [created_at]
      edit:    ~
      new:     ~
```

**lib/form/doctrine/candidateForm.class.php**

```
class candidateForm extends BasecandidateForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    unset( $this['created_at'] );

    $this->widgetSchema['positions'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(
      array( 'multiple' => true, 'model' => 'Position', 'renderer_class' => 'sfWidgetFormSelectCheckbox' )
    );

    $this->validatorSchema['positions'] = new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(
      array( 'multiple' => true, 'model' => 'Position', 'min' => 1 )
    );
  }
}
```

**config/doctrine/schema.yml**

```
candidate:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      unsigned: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    first_name:
      type: string(45)
      notnull: true
    last_name:
      type: string(45)
      notnull: true
    created_at:
      type: integer(4)
      unsigned: true

position:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      unsigned: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(45)

candidatePosition:
  tableName: candidate_position
  columns:
    candidate_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      unsigned: true
      notnull: true
    position_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      unsigned: true
      notnull: true
  relations:
    candidate:
      class: candidate
      local: candidate_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: candidate_positions
    position:
      class: position
      local: position_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: candidate_positions
  indexes:
    fk_candidate_position_candidate1:
      fields: [candidate_id]
    fk_candidate_position_position1:
      fields: [position_id]
```

And this works!  Sort of =/

The checkboxes render to the create and edit screens, but the data doesn't save.  Clearly (?) I need to do some customizaton to the model (lib/model/doctrine/candidate.class.php), and that's where I'm losing focus.  I'm not sure how to get at the candidate[positions] data from within `candidate::save()`

- PHP 5.2.x
- symfony 1.4.3

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but try putting the relation specifications in the main table instead of the reference table, as in http://pastebin.com/CrL0GPrm -- when I do this, the forms work correctly in the admin-generator app with no modifications after `php symfony doctrine:build --all`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you did your schema creating first the db and then execute the build-schema command. Doing that way dosn't create the relationships properly between M:N. So you have to add to your schema.yml this and then rebuild your models, forms and builders.

```
candidate:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      unsigned: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    first_name:
      type: string(45)
      notnull: true
    last_name:
      type: string(45)
      notnull: true
    created_at:
      type: integer(4)
      unsigned: true
  relations:
    Position:
       refClass: candidatePosition
       local: candidate_id
       foreign: position_id

position:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      unsigned: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(45)
  relations:
    Candidate:
       refClass: candidatePosition
       local: position_id
       foreign: candidate_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  My dev machine is in the computer ER at the moment.  Once it is back up to full health, I will continue work on this issue.

Comment: Back on to this problem. This doesn't fix it.  Nothing is saved plus it's directly contrary to doctrine's own documentation on the topic http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/yaml-schema-files/en#relationships:many-to-many

Comment: Where did you see that this schema it's directly contrary to doctrine's documentation? Did you try it?

Comment: Oh yes, I definitely did try it.  And doctrine's documentation says "Doctrine only requires that you specify the relationship on the end where the foreign key exists." In my case, that's the `candidate_position` table.  Both you and Dziamid had me move them to the referenced tables.

Comment: On the end, *not* where the foreign key exists (that would be candidate or position). So, it's not necessary to define the relationship on both ends because, quoting, *"The opposite end of the relationship will be reflected and built on the opposite end"*. Check that in the example, the relationship is defined in the **group** model.

Comment: Well, I've tried it all manner of ways.  1) Only on the reference table 2) only on the referenced tables 3) both 4) only the reference table and just one of the referenced tables.  None of them succeed when it comes to *saving the form*.  No records are created in `candidate_position`.  At any rate, thanks for your help. I'm probably going to delete this question and create a new one with more info.

Comment: Questions: 1) How did you make the schema (manually or by the doctrine:create-schema)? 2) The candidate_position has both fk's assigned?

Comment: 1) Actually, the first version was created by the Doctrine Export Plugin for MySQL Workbench (I like to design schemas visually).  I've hand-tweaked it since. 2) Yes.

Comment: 1) Could you post your actual schema.yml (the position, candidate and position_candidate) part, the form that you're using and the controller part? 2) In your BasePosition do you hace a getCandidates() method?

Comment: I could but won't.  Just look for a new question soon.  This one has too much noise now, and will be deleted.

Comment: Just tried to help you. I'm using this and works fine. If you changed your save method thats probably where the error is. But, it's up to you :)

Comment: Oh, I recognize you're trying to help, I just can't effectively communicate the problem through comments anymore.  When I have time I'll put together a better question with the relevant details.

Comment: Other question is up now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309345/symfony-generator-forms-doctrine-and-mn-relationships

Answer (score 0):

```
//schema.yml
Candidate:
  columns: ~
  relations:
    Position:
      alias: Positions
      refClass: CandidatePosition
      local: candidate_id
      foreign: position_id

Position:
  columns: ~
  relations:
    Candidate:
      alias: Candidates
      refClass: CandidatePosition
      local: position_id
      foreign: candidate_id

CandidatePosition:
  columns:
    candidate_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
    position_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true

//CandidateForm class
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->getWidget('positions_list')->setOption('expanded', true);
  }
```

And it should work right away even with default generator.yml

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  My dev machine is in the computer ER at the moment.  Once it is back up to full health, I will continue work on this issue.

Comment: Back on to this problem. This doesn't fix it.  Nothing is saved plus it's directly contrary to doctrine's own documentation on the topic http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/yaml-schema-files/en#relationships:many-to-many